# Subjunctive mood / Unreal grammar "If I were" with "when"

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, tense-agreement

Which of the two sentences is grammatically more correct/consistent?("drink" or "drank")? 1. "If I were in Paris, I would be sitting at a cozy café, enjoying the beautiful view when I drink my coffee."
2. "If I were in Paris, I would be sitting at a cozy café, enjoying the beautiful view when I drank my coffee."
I am unsure since I assume that "If I were in Paris" means "If I were in Paris right now, which I am not".

Comment: It's not natural to use the past tense "drank" in your sentence in this particular context, because it is something that has not happened yet, in fact it will not happen. It's entirely hypothetical.  I think it would be better to reword it - "while drinking my coffee" or possibly even "and drinking my coffee".

Comment: Really, @BillyKerr? You find “If I were president, I would smile as I **vetoed** that legislation” unnatural?

Comment: @PaulTanerbaum - I said "in this particular context". I didn't say you could never use the past tense, or that it was not grammatical. It just doesn't really work in this context.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I’m curious about the important ways in which you see these contexts as differing. They’re both “entirely hypothetical.” Maybe it has to do with OP’s use of present progressive with the irrealis?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Would be sitting, enjoying, drinking - all seem better together in this particular scenario. Of course, this is only my opinion. However, the more I look at it,  I think it's actually "when I drank" that particularly stands out to me as awkward.  I also think "as I drank" seems OK. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Better would be, “If I were in Paris, I would be sitting at a cozy café, enjoying the beautiful view **as** I **drank** my coffee" or “…**while drinking** my coffee.”